How to define a scala.ValueOf for tuples in scala 3?
The ValueOf type function can be used in the contextual parameters list of a method to pick the single inhabitant of singleton type, or reject the implicit resolution if the type argument isn't a singleton.
enum Color { case red, green, blue }
def singleInhabitantOf[T](using  holder: ValueOf[T]): T = holder.value
println(singleInhabitantOf[Color.red.type] == Color.red) // outputs true

But it is limited. It doesn't work with tuples whose component types are all singletons.
singleInhabitantOf[(Color.red.type, Color.blue.type)] // compile error

The error message is: No singleton value available for (Color.red, Color.blue); eligible singleton types for ValueOf synthesis include literals and stable paths.
So I tried to create a version for tuples this way:
import scala.Tuple

type ValuesOf[T <: Tuple] <: Tuple = T match {
    case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
    case h *: t => ValueOf[h] *: ValuesOf[t]
}

def singleInhabitantsOf[T<:Tuple](using holder: ValuesOf[T]): Tuple = holder // a tuple mapping is missing here but how to implement it is another question.

singleInhabitantsOf[(Color.red.type, Color.blue.type)] // Copile error

Unfortunately, the compiler complains saying: No given instance of type ValuesOf[(Color.red, Color.blue)] was found for parameter holder.
Apparently it looks for a tuple instance in the implicit context instead of synthetizing a tuple with the singletons instances.
However
summonAll[ValuesOf[(Color.red.type, Color.blue.type)]]

compiles and runs fine.
So I could rewrite the method using summonAll like this
inline def singleInhabitantsOf2[T <: Tuple]: Tuple = summonAll[ValuesOf[T]] 

But this solution is not useful for my final purpose, for which the check of singletonness should be in the method signature, such that the compiler don't start processing the body if something is wrong.

Edit @DmytroMitin showed me that the previous paragraph is incorrect. It is okay and sometimes unavoidable to involve the body of the given clause in determining when it provides an instance or not.

Any idea on how to define a ValueOf that works with tuples in the context parameters list?

Why not just use a simple head-tail derivation of a custom type class like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/6URuvrBQTXKlqNBC6SH2RA/5

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The method GetSingletonValue.of works fine with literal arguments. But for some reason it fails when applied to a Mirror.Sum.MirrorElemTypes.
The following def don't work:
inline def summandsOf[T](using mirror: Mirror.SumOf[T]): Tuple = GetSingletonValue.of[T]

To make it work its necessary to use summonInline
inline def summandsOf[T](using mirror: Mirror.SumOf[T]): Tuple = summonInline[GetSingletonValue[mirror.MirroredElemTypes]].value

Don't know why.

Moving all decisors to the signature also works


Readren, what about this? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/6URuvrBQTXKlqNBC6SH2RA/20 - If this solves your problem I am happy to post it as an answer. C.C. @DmytroMitin any feedback you may have is greatly appreciated :)

I prefer your original version. Adding the ofEnum method seems a workaround to a specific problem? Isn't there another way to make the ofValue method work when used in the summandOf I mentioned above? Why does it fail in the first place?

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Your solution works also with simple types which may be useful for other users so I think it may be beneficial to others you post your answer.
I already have my own version based on yours and Dmitro which I copied here "https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BAKzNFtURcuUu2VUPdZfeg".

Well the second solution is the same as the original one just with the addition of ofEnum. ofEnum is just a convenience method since the valueOf already works assuming you do the indirections to get the Mirror of the enum. Anyways, posting the code as an answer right now.

Type classes and match types are two ways to perform type-level calculations in Scala 3 (like type projections and type classes in Scala 2, type families and type classes in Haskell).
Mixing type classes and match types can be tricky:
How to prove that `Tuple.Map[H *: T, F] =:= (F[H] *: Tuple.Map[T, F])` in Scala 3
scala 3 map tuple to futures of tuple types and back
Scala3 type matching with multiple types

It seems you want type classes rather than match types
trait ValuesOf[T <: Tuple]:
  def value: T

object ValuesOf:
  given ValuesOf[EmptyTuple] with
    val value = EmptyTuple

  given [h, t <: Tuple](using vh: ValueOf[h], vt: ValuesOf[t]): ValuesOf[h *: t] with
    val value = vh.value *: vt.value

def singleInhabitantsOf[T <: Tuple](using holder: ValuesOf[T]): T = holder.value

singleInhabitantsOf[(Color.red.type, Color.blue.type)] // (red,blue)


With match types you can do
type SingleInhabitantsOf[T <: Tuple] <: Tuple = T match
  case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
  case h *: t => h *: SingleInhabitantsOf[t]

inline def singleInhabitantsOf0[T <: Tuple]: SingleInhabitantsOf[T] =
  inline erasedValue[T] match
    case _: EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
    case _: (h *: t) => valueOf[h] *: singleInhabitantsOf0[t]

// to specify return type, not necessary
inline def singleInhabitantsOf[T <: Tuple]: T = summonFrom {
  case given (SingleInhabitantsOf[T] =:= T) => singleInhabitantsOf0[T]
}

singleInhabitantsOf[(Color.red.type, Color.blue.type)] // (red,blue)


Using standard operations on tuples you can do
type ValuesOf[T <: Tuple] = Tuple.Map[T, ValueOf]

type InvValueOf[V] = V match
  case ValueOf[a] => a

type SingleInhabitantsOf[T <: Tuple] = Tuple.Map[ValuesOf[T], InvValueOf]

// can't express return type
inline def singleInhabitantsOf0[T <: Tuple] /*: Tuple.Map[? <: ValuesOf[T], InvValueOf]*//*: SingleInhabitantsOf[T]*/ =
  val valuesOf = summonAll[ValuesOf[T]]
  valuesOf.map[InvValueOf]([b] => (y: b) => y match
    case v: ValueOf[a] => v.value
  ): Tuple.Map[valuesOf.type, InvValueOf]

// to specify return type, not necessary
inline def singleInhabitantsOf[T <: Tuple]: T = summonFrom {
  case _: (SingleInhabitantsOf[T] =:= T) => singleInhabitantsOf0[T]
}

singleInhabitantsOf[(Color.red.type, Color.blue.type)] // (red,blue)



But this solution is not useful for my final purpose, for which the check of singletonness should be in the method signature, such that the compiler don't start processing the body if something is wrong.

Sounds like a little weird requirement. You can always "hide" implicit parameters from the left at the right. In Scala 2 you can rewrite
def foo[A](implicit tc: TC[A]): Unit = ()

as
def foo[A]: Unit = macro fooImpl[A]

def fooImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  c.inferImplicitValue(weakTypeOf[TC[A]])
  q"()"
}

In Scala 3 you can rewrite
def foo[A](using TC[A]): Unit = ()

as
inline def foo[A]: Unit =
  summonInline[TC[A]]
  ()

Maybe you could tell more about your actual problem (maybe starting a new question) and we could look whether it can be solved via match types, summonAll, constValueTuple and other stuff from scala.compiletime.*.


But I think it isn't a good practice to relay on compilation errors as decider. That is error message unfriendly and hard to understand.

I do not mean to argue on code styles but error messages depend on a developer
def foo[A](using TC[A]): Unit = ()

foo[Int] // No given instance of type App.TC[Int] was found for parameter x$1 of method foo in object App

inline def foo[A]: Unit =
  summonInline[TC[A]]
  ()

foo[Int] // No given instance of type App.TC[Int] was found

def foo[A](using @implicitNotFound("No TC!!!") tc: TC[A]): Unit = ()

foo[Int] // No TC!!!

inline def foo[A]: Unit =
  summonFrom {
    case _: TC[A] => ()
    case _ => error("No TC!!!")
  }

foo[Int] // No TC!!!


I do not insist that you should always use implicits "on the right" rather than implicitls "on the left". I just wanted to show you that you have a choice. Surely, implicits "on the left" are more standard. But implicits "on the right" can sometimes be more flexible. For example please see my answer in (already mentioned) scala 3 map tuple to futures of tuple types and back . I'm using there implicits "on the right" nested deeply in the method body. This could be harder to achieve with implicits "on the left".

About "you can always hide implicit parameters from the left at the right", what if there are two givens for the same type? They should be exclusive with each other. Should that exclusiveness be determined entirely by the signatures or may it also be determined by the compileness of the body?

Can you customize the implicit not found error message (with @implicitNotFound) when fired by the summonInline method?

@Readren Yeah, you can have custom compile errors. c.echo/c.info/c.warning/c.error/c.abort in Scala 2, scala.compiletime.error in Scala 3. Not sure I understand about "exclusiveness". Maybe some little code snippet for illustration? At Scastie for example if not in a new question.

@Readren summonFrom { case given TC[A] => ???;  case _ => error("no TC") } https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html

@Readren If you have two implicits (givens) then either an implicit can be resolved upon a call (based on less special type/more special type, lower-priority implicit/higher-priority implicit) or it's an error (ambiguous implicits). That's the same for implicit/using parameter on the left or c.inferImplicitValue/summonInline on the right.

If I understand your words, what determines whether or not a given clause provides an instance doesn't just have to be the given's signature (as I thought), but whether the body compiles correctly or not can also be involved in the decision; if and only if the compilation error occurs in a call to a summonInline or inferImplicitValue. Correct?
I know that a given clause whose body don't compile will never provide an instance. But I think it isn't a good practice to relay on compilation errors as decider. That is error message unfriendly and hard to understand.

How would be the answer using match types instead of type classes?

@Readren constValueTuple

@Readren Actually, since constValue doesn't work for red.type, constValueTuple doesn't work for (red.type, blue.type) ( constValue[1], constValueTuple[(1, 2)], valueOf[red.type] work). I updated my answer.

The approach using match types (instead of type clases) tried in the question worked when in the body with summon but not in the signature. Why?

In your scastie the SingleInhabitantsOf match type does not resemble the ValuesOf match type in the question. In the scastie the ValueOf is not being applied to the head.
I think that the reason why the summonAll[ValuesOf[Color]] works but the context parameter using holder: ValuesOf[T] fails is that both are tuples and summonAll is designed to summon all elements of the tuple separately and the implicit resolution of a context parameter tries to summon the whole tuple in one shot.

@Readren summonAll returns a tuple of instances of a type class. summonAll applies summon (Scala 3 variant of Scala 2 implicitly) to all elements of a tuple. See the link. If in a scope there are implicits of types A, B this doesn't necessarily mean that there is an implicit of type (A, B).

@Readren By the way, implicitly[summonAll[ValuesOf[T]]] (from your question) doesn't make sense because inside implicitly[...] only a type can be but summonAll[...] is a value. summonAll[ValuesOf[Color]] doesn't make sense either because Color is a not a subtype of Tuple.

Ups. That was a copy paste error. Thank you for pointing it out. I will edit the question.

This answer deserves many more up-votes. It is an intensive course of the scala-3 type system

Another approach is just to use a traditional head-tail derivation of the typeclass.
I am almost sure you can reuse the existing ValueOf one, but personally I prefer to write my own one just to avoid any issues:
trait GetSingletonValue[A]:
  def value: A
  
object GetSingletonValue:
  /** Construct a GetSingletonValue for any value for which there is a ValueOf instance. */  
  given [A](using ev: ValueOf[A]): GetSingletonValue[A] with
    override final val value: A = ev.value

  /** Base case for the Tuple recursion. */
  given GetSingletonValue[EmptyTuple] with
    override final val value: EmptyTuple = EmptyTuple

  /** Recursive case for the Tuple recursion. */
  given [A, T <: Tuple](using head: GetSingletonValue[A], tail: GetSingletonValue[T]): GetSingletonValue[A *: T] with
    override final val value: A *: T = head.value *: tail.value
end GetSingletonValue

You can then request an instance for any singleton:
summon[GetSingletonValue[Color.Green.type]].value // Green

And of any Tuple of singletons:
summon[GetSingletonValue[(Color.Red.type, Color.Blue.type)]].value // (Red, Blue)

You can then add a couple of useful helper methods to reduce the boilerplate:
inline def apply[A](using ev: GetSingletonValue[A]): ev.type = ev

inline def ofValue[A](using ev: GetSingletonValue[A]): A = ev.value

And use them like this:
GetSingletonValue.ofValue[Color.Green.type] // Green
GetSingletonValue.ofValue[(Color.Red.type, Color.Blue.type) // (Red, Blue)

Now, you want to just be able to get all the singletons of a given enum.
For that, we would need to materialize a tuple type that represents all the types of the enum. Thankfully Scala 3 already give us that in the form of Mirror.SumOf[T]#MirroredElemTypes.
val colorMirror = summon[scala.deriving.Mirror.SumOf[Color]]
GetSingletonValue.ofValue[colorMirror.MirroredElemTypes] // (Red, Green, Blue)

However, having to materialize the Mirror ourselves in order to request the values is redundant boilerplate.
Thus, we could just provide a nice helper:
inline def ofEnum[E](using m: scala.deriving.Mirror.SumOf[E], ev: GetSingletonValue[m.MirroredElemTypes]): m.MirroredElemTypes = ev.value

You can also code it like this if you prefer:
inline def ofEnum2[E](using m: scala.deriving.Mirror.SumOf[E]): m.MirroredElemTypes =
    scala.compiletime.summonInline[GetSingletonValue[m.MirroredElemTypes]].value


They both are essentially the same thing. Personally, I prefer the first one, it is more usual for Scala 2 folks and needs less macro wizardry.

Both work as expected:
GetSingletonValue.ofEnum[Color] // (Red, Green, Blue)
GetSingletonValue.ofEnum2[Color] // (Red, Green, Blue)


You can see the code running in Scastie.

A final note, AFAIK, in Scala 3 the head-tail approach is not recommended any more due to "high-level" constructs for derivation. But, personally, I always struggle to use them for a lot of reasons. Shapeless 3 is a better approach to the high-level idea, but I still prefer simple recursion.

Nice approach, Luis

@LuisMiguelMekíaSuarez Isn't Dmytro's solution also using head-tail derivation? Is there another way to solve this other than that?

@Readren oh right, I got a bit distracted by the whole macro stuff at the end. But yeah, is mostly the same, mine is a little bit more general.
